# changing the parameter value in IparameterInspector WCF RESTful

Tags: wcf, rest, restful-url, wcf-rest

I am trying to change the value of the parameter in IParameterInspector while doing the validation. The parameters that are string, works fine. But I need int as parameters. and if the parameter is not supplied in the RESTful call, I need to default it.

If the url does not contain anything for int parameter, it fails. However, in the same case of string parameter, if its not supplied, it takes the default values.

I use querystring format for passing the parameters. and I am just trying to run it on the browser.

Is there any way for this to work? or do I need to make all the parameters as string.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the parameters string.  This will be fixed in the next version of the WCF Web APIS http://wcf.codeplex.com